# C# & ASP.NET MVC: How to populate a data object model within another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that handles questions to display on an ASP.NET MVC form. One of the properties within my `Question` model is the type of question the item is (`QuestionType`); this is its own separate model class, however my problem is I'm having trouble reading the `QuestionType` values from the database and then updating the `QuestionType` property within my `Question` model class.

For example, I'd like to be able to do the following, but I don't know how to populate my `QuestionType` correctly:

```
string myQuestionTypeName = model.Question.QuestionType.Name;
```

`Question` model class:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }    
}
```

`QuestionType` model class:

```
public class QuestionType
{
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Question` data - pulls from my `Question` database table.

My stored procedure returns:

- QuestionId
- Name
- QuestionTypeId

Code:

```
public List<Question> PullList()
{
    List<Question> questionList = new List<question>();

    using (Sql sql = new Sql(Sql.Connection.MyDbConnectionName, "storedProc_PullQuestions"))
    {
        using (var ds = sql.GetDataSet())
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Question question = new Question();
                question.QuestionId = dr.Field<int>("QuestionId");
                question.Name = dr.Field<string>("Name");
                question.QuestionType = //??? Not sure what to do here.  I have the "QuestionTypeId" from the stored procedure, but not sure how to populate this object based on that id.

                questionList.Add(question);
            }
        }
    }

    return questionList;
}
```

`QuestionType` data - pulls from my `QuestionType` table; my stored procedure returns:

- QuestionTypeId
- Name

Code:

```
public List<QuestionType> PullList()
{
    List<QuestionType> questionTypeList = new List<QuestionType>();

    using (Sql sql = new Sql(Sql.Connection.MyDbConnectionName, "storedProc_PullQuestionTypes"))
    {
        using (var ds = sql.GetDataSet())
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                QuestionType questionType = new QuestionType();
                questionType.QuestionTypeId = dr.Field<int>("QuestionTypeId");
                questionType.Name = dr.Field<string>("Name");

                questionTypeList.Add(questionType);
            }
        }
    }

    return questionTypeList;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: I think you should modify your stored procedure (or create a new one) so that it returns the related `QuestionType` data along with the `Question` data. Otherwise you'll end up querying for `QuestionType` for each `Question` inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join 2 tables in your select query of stored procedure and after this

```cs
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     Question question = new Question();
     question.QuestionType = new QuestionType();
     question.QuestionId = dr.Field<int>("QuestionId");
     question.Name = dr.Field<string>("Name");
      question.QuestionType.QuestionTypeId = dr.Field<int>"QuestionTypeId");
     question.QuestionType.Name = dr.Field<string>("QuestionTypeName");

     questionList.Add(question);
}
```